show name instead of Id while using MudSelect and @bind-SelectedValues
i have the problem that when i have a dropdown in Blazor like this
<MudSelect T="Guid" Label="Items" MultiSelection="true" @bind-SelectedValues="selectedItemIds" Variant="Variant.Outlined" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter"
    Required RequiredError="select item">

    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        <MudSelectItem T="Guid" Value="@item.id">@item.name</MudSelectItem>
    
</MudSelect>

when I have chosen the names of items I want they are displayed at the top but only there Ids and not there name, how can I fix so that the names are displayed instead of the Id. its for a form so I need the id for the post/put
Tried to mange so the selectedItemIds i used for a GetNames function so i have the name from the  selectedItemIds but i cant find a way to display it

Have a look at https://mudblazor.com/components/select#multiselect-customized-selection-text
You can use MultiSelectionTextFunc to customize the way the selected values are displayed.
<MudSelect ... MultiSelectionTextFunc="@(new Func<List<string>, string>(GetMultiSelectionText))" ... >

private string GetMultiSelectionText(List<string> selectedItemIdsAsString)
{
    return GetNames(selectedItemIdsAsString);
}

As it seems it's only possible to use Func<List<string>, string> for the MutliSelectionTextFunc. So my old answer was incorrect.
If you just want to display all the names in a simple way, store the values as a List of your items object (private List<Item> _selectedValues), ToStringFunc="x => x.Name" and maybe Delimiter="; "
See my answer to a newer question
